# GitLab CI/CD run step only if on correct branch AND it has changes

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want a step in the build process only to run on the `master` branch, if there where changes to the `src` folder.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file thus contains:

```
build:php:
    stage: build
    image: alpine
    interruptible: true
    needs: [ "test:php" ]
    script:
        - do stuff // abreviated for simplicity
    rules:
        -   if: $LANGUAGE_RELEASE
            when: never
        -   if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == "master"' # run for production test branch
        -   changes:
                - src/*
```

However, the issue here is, that it also runs on the `dev` branch, when I change anything.

**Question:** Is the a way to have this step only run, both conditions (the branch and the changes) are met?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `rules` keyword, the [`rules:if` clause](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) may be used, with the variable `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`.

Thus, something like below to specify `master` as the only branch to run the job:

```yaml
build:php:
    stage: build
    # ...
    rules:
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    # ...
```

(Rules are applied in order)

The documentation reference for common if clauses available is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#common-if-clauses-for-rules).

---

Now to combine an `if` and `changes` rule, you'll need to use

```yaml
build:php:
    stage: build
    # ...
    rules:
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
         changes:
           - file1 # single file
           - folder/**/* # folder including all files and subfolders
    # ...
```

You can read more about changes used in rules [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) and read the full changes specification [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges).

With the initial setup there where two issues:

1. the changes where seen as a new rule (since they had a `-` in front)
2. `src/*` only takes the `src` folder in consideration, not sub folders, for that you'll need `src/**/*`

---

It is also possible to use the `only` keyword to specify `master` as the only branch to run the job. Despite being simple, this is no longer encouraged and it cannot be used together with `rules` ([`only`/`except` reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)).

Example:

```yaml
build:php:
    stage: build
    # ...
    only:
       - master
    # ...
```

Comment: One issue with this: `only` and `rules` are incompatible and AFAIK GitLab is encouraging the move to `rules`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did not read the entire snippet and gave only the "fast" solution, I am sorry. I'll update the answer :)

Comment: This works for the branch itself, however if I try to combine it with a changes rule, ex.

```
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == "master"'
          changes:
            - api/config/*
            - api/src/*
            - api/tests/*
            - api/migrations/*
            - api/composer.lock
            - api/symfony.lock
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run `rules:changes` on the `master` branch.

Gitlab docs says:

> You should use rules: changes only with branch pipelines or merge
> request pipelines. You can use rules: changes with other pipeline
> types, but rules: changes always evaluates to true when there is no
> Git push event. Tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, manual pipelines,
> and so on do not have a Git push event associated with them.

It means `changes` gives always `true` if there is different type than `branches` or `merge_requests`